# Looking for a good diff/merge app for Mac

Tags: macos

When working on Windows i use WinMerge.
I am looking for something similar for Mac.

I need to be able to merge files and folders (recursively).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Off topic here. But I'll guess that Emacs might have some variant on Mac which fits the bill.

Comment: I have been using meld in ubuntu for sometime now, it is good and from their site I see they have an OS X version also. Here is the link [http://meldmerge.org/]

Answer (score 2):

`FileMerge` is a tool that comes with Xcode. In Terminal.app you can do a diff with it, named `opendiff` there. See `man opendiff`

Comment: But x code takes *so long* to install. It 20 minutes and it's still only half installed.

Answer (score 0):

[Kaleidoscope](http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com/) for diff, Gitbox for merging (you'll have to use Git though). The two can work together.

Comment: is there anything free?

Comment: The already mentioned FileMerge.app as well as all the commandline tools are free.

Comment: Since version 2, Kaleidoscope can also do merge. I'm using it and satisfied.